# Gulp.src match folder with square brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've automated all tasks from my project using gulp.

However I have a specific name folder with square brackets in its name (yes, it's required to have square brackets in it's name on purpose) and this seems not to work with gulp.
I need to target that folder and minify the javascript in it. I tried using a regex match pattern, but as long as I read gulp is using blob or either I don't understand blob or I am doing this wrong

Let's say I have a folder named with scripts inside of it : [testFolder] > script1.js, script2.js
This is how I target it with code.

```
function minifyJs() {
  return gulp.src('resources/[testFolder]/**/*.js') // not working
  return gulp.src('resources/\[.*testFolder\]/**/*.js) // not working either desipte I've tested 
       it on various things
    .pipe(minify({ noSource: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/[testFolder]')) // this is working pretty much fine
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some days of trying to make it work, it seems this is working for both macOS / linux and Windows (tested on windows 10)
Thanks for @Saeed help in the answer below.

```
// MAC / LINUX OS
function minifyJs() {
return gulp.src('resources/\\[testFolder\\]/**/*.js') // note the \\[name\\] escape here
 .pipe(minify({ noSource: true }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/[testFolder]')) // this is working for both
}

// WINDOWS
function minifyJs() {
return gulp.src('resources/[[]testFolder]/**/*.js') // note [[]name] escape here
  .pipe(minify({ noSource: true }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/[testFolder]')) // this is working for both
}
```

This is for windows

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\` for escaping `[]`.

```
function minifyJs() {
  return gulp.src('resources/\\[testFolder\\]/**/*.js') // not working
    .pipe(minify({ noSource: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/[testFolder]')) // this is working pretty much fine
}
```

For more information read [globs/segments-and-separators](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/explaining-globs/#segments-and-separators) and [How do I match a square bracket literal using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349156/how-do-i-match-a-square-bracket-literal-using-regex)

Comment: thanks a lot fo the answer, however this didn't work either. Before I post this on the forum I tried using blob and escaping characters and it didn't work...
I used  gulp.src('resources/\\[testFolder\\]/*.js') and it still doesn't match the folder and the files inside of it.. Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: I tested it, moving a file inside `[test]`folder to somewhere else and it worked. @iliajanev

Comment: Did you try just moving files from one file to another?? `return src('resources/\\[testFolder\\]/**/*.js') .pipe(dest('output/')); }` ?? without any process?! @IliaHanev

Comment: It still doesn't work.. I tried the heck I could and it still ain't working, what do you mean by any process. I am creating a gulp.task('minify') and execute it from the command line. The src matching works for folders with non square brackets, the folders with square brackets are just like ignored, nothing happens to them at all, not even moving the files.

Comment: here's picture from my editor and anyting [picture](https://ibb.co/xYN6cqb)
The second return statements works.. while the first one doesn't...

Comment: And [this](https://ibb.co/qJhz6vV) is image from my test. @IliaHanev :/

Comment: This is really strange. Am I missing a dependency or something? What is your gulp version? I tried this on a blob matcher online and everything's working but it's not working on my side, sadly.

Comment: I ran it with gulp task also! and again it worked correctly. `CLI version: 2.2.0 Local version: 4.0.2` @IliaHanev

Comment: This is a miracle, still have on idea why it doesn't work for me. I am marking your answer as "solved the problem" and thank you very much for spending time to help solve this. Guess this could be a problem with the setup or who knows.. I am running this on windows machine. I would rather refactor all the folders to work without that [testFolder] name rather than debugging gulp.

Comment: Good luck. @IliaHanev